# "Login failed for user" when opening an MDF

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class Reg
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim myConn As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim sqlstring, ide, name, fname, cty As String

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub submitbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles submitbtn.Click
        ide = idbox.Text
        name = namebox.Text
        fname = fatherbox.Text
        cty = countrybox.Text

        myConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=C:\USERS\DREAM THEATER\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\WEBSITES\WEBAPP\APP_DATA\DATAAJIT.MDF;Integrated Security=True")
        myConn.Open()

        sqlstring = " INSERT INTO Test (Id,name,father,country) VALUES (" + ide + ",'" + name + "','" + fname + "','" + cty + "')"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlstring, myConn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        myConn.Close()
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, True)

    End Sub
End Class
```

When I run this code error occured as follows

> SQl exception was unhandled by user code
>   Cannot open database "C:\USERS\DREAM THEATER\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\WEBSITES\WEBAPP\APP_DATA\DATAAJIT.MDF" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user 'lanrad\Dream Theater'.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Initial Catalog want the LOGICAL NAME of the database not the physical file name. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Inside the web.config, at Initial Catalog put the name of the database and not the full path of the .mdf.

Also because you have Integrated security = true check if your user(you in this situation) exists in the security section of the database, under logins

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myconnectionstring" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=DATAAJIT.MDF;Integrated Security=False;uid=Dream Theater;password=mypassword; "/>
  </connectionStrings>
I have edited above code in web.config .. but the problem is not still solve.. How to fix this .

Comment: You're specifying the Initial Catalog in the code posted in your question above when you create the connection.  Specify the connection string in one place or the other, not both.  (Preferably the web.config, obviously).

Comment: No user exists in the security section of the database. And I tried to insert user ID and password by Right clicking on Databasefile(from Server Explorer)-->Modify connection-->Advance by Selecting Integrated Security to false. Says Login failed for user "username".
How can I fix this ??@Thanos Markou

Comment: @AjitDarnal Is it SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: SQL Server 2012   @Thanos Markou

Comment: Finally it is solved .I had just attached .mdf file using SQL Server 2012 ... It is working